# Matlab HDF5: Read DIMENSION_LIST attribute

Tags: matlab, attributes, hdf5

I'm trying to read HDF5 files with Matlab. I created the files in Fortran, which is only relevant in that I used `h5dsattach_scale_f` to attached scale datasets to each dimension of my given primary dataset. Most of my logic works well, but I'm having trouble reading the attributes of my primary dataset in order to get at the attached scales.

I start by iterating through each dataset in the file. Once I know I have my primary dataset, I iterate through its attributes with this call:

`[status, index_out, SD] = H5A.iterate(dset_id, 'H5_INDEX_NAME', 'H5_ITER_NATIVE', 0, @hdf5_sds_attr_iter, SD);`

That calls this function for every attribute:

```
function [status, SD] = hdf5_sds_attr_iter(dset_id, attr_name, info, SD)
    status = 0;
    disp(attr_name);

    if ~strcmp(attr_name, 'DIMENSION_LIST')
        return;
    end
    attr_id = H5A.open(dset_id, attr_name, 'H5P_DEFAULT');

    space = H5A.get_space (attr_id);
    [~, dims, ~] = H5S.get_simple_extent_dims(space);

    info2 = H5A.get_info(attr_id);
    disp(info2);
    rdata = H5A.read(attr_id, 'H5ML_DEFAULT');
    disp(rdata);
    for i = 1:dims
        disp(rdata{i});
    end
    H5S.close(space);
    H5A.close(attr_id);
end
```

This is the output:

```
DIMENSION_LIST
     3

    corder_valid: 1
          corder: 0
            cset: 0
       data_size: 48

    [8x1 uint8]
    [8x1 uint8]
    [8x1 uint8]

  184
   17
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0

   32
   28
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0

  240
   29
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
```

If I do h5dump on the dataset, this is what that attribute looks like:

```
  ATTRIBUTE "DIMENSION_LIST" {
     DATATYPE  H5T_VLEN { H5T_REFERENCE { H5T_STD_REF_OBJECT }}
     DATASPACE  SIMPLE { ( 3 ) / ( 3 ) }
     DATA {
     (0): (DATASET 1400 /beamdata scale rank 1 ),
     (1): (DATASET 6512 /beamdata scale rank 2 ),
     (2): (DATASET 6976 /beamdata scale rank 3 )
     }
  }
```

Since those numbers (1400, 6512, 6976) do not appear elsewhere in the dump, I don't know how to use them or the output of `H5A.read` (`rdata`) to actually get at the scale data. The [Matlab HDF5 documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/hdf5-files.html) is rather silent on what to do with attribute data. Does anyone know how to process attribute reference data correctly?